# Magento 2: How to run CLI command from another CLI command class?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm working on a custom CLI command & I was wondering what's the best way to call other commands from the PHP code (without shell_exec() or similar).
For example:
When running "php bin/magento my:custom:command", it'll do it's thing & in the end will run "php bin/magento cache:flush".

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Magento CLI is built on top of Symfony Console. You can load up and run other commands with this component as such:

```
$arguments = new ArrayInput(['command' => 'my:custom:command']);
$this->getApplication()->find('my:custom:command')->run($arguments, $output);

$arguments = new ArrayInput(['command' => 'cache:flush']);
$this->getApplication()->find('cache:flush')->run($arguments, $output);
```

More information [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/calling_commands.html). Although it's unlikely to be a problem for you, please note that the documentation suggests this is not always the best idea:

> Most of the times, calling a command from code that is not executed on the command line is not a good idea. The main reason is that the command's output is optimized for the console and not to be passed to other commands.